# Задание: перевернуть список циклом. Есть код, но по какой-то причине он не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот сам код:

```
j = len(list1) 

for j in range(len(list1),0):
 slovo += list1[j]
 j -= 1
```

Python ошибки не выдает, просто останавливается на моменте между

```
j = len(list1) и

for j in range(len(list1,0):
```

Comment: Не очень хорошо одинаковые названия давать переменным в одинаковом контексте :) Сначала у вас переменная `j` хранила длину 'list1', при выполнении цикла ее значение изменится в соответствии с тем, что вернет `range` и нет смысла пытаться ее поменять -- она на следующей итерации в `for` примет следующее значение из `range`

Answer (score 2):

Вообще разворот списка делается так:

```
print (list1[::-1])
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но мне сейчас нужно именно переворот списка циклом. Есть у вас идеи почему код не работает?

Comment: Потому что у вас j -= 1 и вы не используете отладчик.

Comment: а что такое отладчик?

Comment: @Михаил отладчик это такая штука, которая позволяет посмотреть как на самом деле работает программа. Без его освоения в программировании делать, считайте, нечего.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, ну еще вместо отладчика можно впихнуть в код побольше `print`'ов и смотреть по ним как алгоритм отрабатывается :)

Comment: @gil9red это тоже своего рода отладчик, но от безысходности :-D

Answer (score 2):

Сделать переворот через цикл `for`:

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
new_items = []

for i in range(len(items)):
    new_items.append(items[len(items) - i - 1])

# OR:
# for i in range(len(items), 0, -1):
#     new_items.append(items[i - 1])

# OR:
# for i in reversed(range(len(items))):
#     new_items.append(items[i])    

print(new_items)  # [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Или сделать через `while`:

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
new_items = []

index = len(items) - 1

while index >= 0:
    item = items[index]
    new_items.append(item)

    index -= 1

print(new_items)  # [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

---

Помимо алгоритма через цикл и разворота через срез (`[::-1]`), есть конкретные функции:

```
list1.reverse()
list1 = reversed(list1)
# Чтобы получить именно тип список
list1 = list(reversed(list1))
```

[reverse](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) разворачивает элементы в самом списке

[reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=reversed#reversed) возвращает итератор списка с развернутыми элементами